# XSLT on XML breaks blockquote in HTML output

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tei

I'm having a problem with the HTML output from an XSL transformation on XML. In the XML, you can see there is a page break  in the middle of a paragraph

. The stylesheet inserts a visual page break at this point, but this breaks the  formatting of the whole paragraph. The lines that appear after the page break are indented correctly, but the line spacing is too close together, it looks the same as a normal paragraph. Is there any way to fix this without a major overhaul?

I believe I've included all the relevant code:

BEGIN XML

```
<floatingText xml:id="foo.001" type="bar">
<opener>
    <address>
        <addrLine>Address</addrLine>
        <addrLine>
            <date when="2017-04-26">April 26, 2017</date>
        </addrLine>
    </address>
    <salute>
        <hi rend="italic">Hello world.</hi>
    </salute>
</opener>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Pellentesque eget odio<pb type="recto" n="19"/> pellentesque, mollis 
mi et, malesuada
        est. Duis eleifend ullamcorper justo, vitae accumsan ante 
porta id.</p>
    <closer>
        <salute>Yours,</salute>
        <signed>Me</signed>
    </closer>
</body>
</floatingText>
```

END XML

BEGIN XSL TRANSFORMATION

```
<xsl:template match="pb[@n]">
<LEFT>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap"> - - - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - -
                <font face="Arial" size="-2">
                    [Begin&#160;page&#160;<xsl:value-of select="@n"
                    />]</font> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="10">&#160;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LEFT>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@rend = 'center'">
        <p/>
        <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
            <center>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </center>
        </font>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
            <p/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<xsl:apply-templates/>
        </font>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="closer | opener | dateline">
<font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
    <blockquote>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <br/>
    </blockquote>
</font>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="salute | signed">
<font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
    <p/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <br/>
</font>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="floatingText[@type = 'letter']">
<blockquote>
    <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </font>
</blockquote>
</xsl:template>
```

END XSL

BEGIN HTML OUTPUT

```
<font xmlns="" face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
<blockquote>
    <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
        <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
            <blockquote>
                <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
                    <br />Address
                </font>
                <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
<br /> April 26, 2017.
                </font>
                <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
<p /><br /> 
                    <font face="Arial, sans-serif"><i>Hello world.
</i>
                    </font><br />
                </font><br />
            </blockquote>
        </font>
        <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
            <p />&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque posuere, erat non 
commodo ornare, nunc nulla faucibus mauris, quis venenatis urna 
turpis eu lorem. Pellentesque eget odio
            <CENTER>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&#160;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                            <font face="Arial" size="-2">
[dashes are here]&#160;begin&#160;page&#160;19&#160;[dashes are here]
                            </font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="10">&#160;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </CENTER>
            pellentesque, mollis mi et, malesuada est. Duis eleifend 
ullamcorper justo, vitae accumsan ante porta id.
        </font>
        <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
            <blockquote>
                <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
<p /><br />Yours,<br /></font>
                <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
<p /><br />Me<br />
                </font><br />
            </blockquote>
        </font>
    </font>
</blockquote>
</font>
```

END HTML

Comment: probably not "without major overhaul", you would have to split the `<blockquote>`s at the `<pb>`s but they may be at a deeper level of the structure

Comment: I guess I meant to say, would it be possible by just manipulating the the XSLT? Or possible with a simple script?

Comment: A possible answerer could be interested in: will the pb always be a child of a `<p>` below `<body>`? Can there be at most one?

Comment: @StefanHegny <p> would always be a child of <body>. I'm quite sure there are no cases in the corpus where there is more than one <pb> in a <p> but there are always multiple <p> children in <body>.

Comment: Do I understand it right that you can't use @style (or CSS in general) for some reason? And hell, I haven't seen <center> for a while.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to render all text nodes within <p> separately:

```
<xsl:template match="p//text()">
    <font face="Arial Unicode MS, sans-serif" size="-1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </font>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this could affect the rendering of other descendants of `p`, like `hi` and so on. You would have to introduce separate templates for such elements.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @friedemann_bach 's comment, here's what we do: We insert a pipe symbol in the regular text flow and additionally a div which is then moved to the right place (in a marginal column on the left) via css. Here is xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="pb">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@break='no'">
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">pageNumbers</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('p. ', @n)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and style.css:

```
.pageNumbers {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -12%;
    display: block;
}
```